# Can dict been shared between parent process and child process?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

Please check below code

```
from multiprocessing import Process

return_dict = dict({})
print "address in parent %s " % id(return_dict)


def f(return_dict):
    print "address in child %s " % id(return_dict)


p = Process(target=f, args=(return_dict, ))
p.start()
p.join()
```

The output is

```
address in parent 23059696 
address in child 23059696
```

I print the address of dict in parent process and child process. they are the same. But if I change the dict in child process, the change will not affect the dict in parent process.

So I assume the dict are two different object in memory. But why there address are the same?

Some may say it is relative address in  process, but why relative address need to be the same?

Comment: Now try this on Windows. :-)

Comment: Show what you mean by "But if I change the dict in child process, the change will not affect the dict in parent process."

Comment: Pick one or the other: `return_dict = dict()` or `return_dict = {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your platform, `multiprocessing` uses *forking* to spawn a child process. Forking a process this way lets the child process use the *exact same memory regions*, in a copy-on-write scheme.

So when the child process starts and the dictionary is passed into the `f()` function, *it is still the same dictionary object*. It has been 'inherited' from the parent process.

Next, the `id()` value of an object is the *virtual memory address*. Memory is virtualised by your OS; each process is given regions of physical memory, but their addresses into that space are translated by the OS. When forking, the child process is given the same virtual address space, and copy-on-write *transparently* produces a copy when needed, where the same virtual memory address range now maps onto a different piece of physical memory. So from the point of view of the Python child process, the `id()` doesn't change, but it no longer refers to the same piece of physical memory. The *combination of `os.getpid()` and `id()`* is unique, but the value of `id()` alone is not, not across processes.

If you run the same code on Windows (which doesn't support forking), you'll see that the ID is always going to be different. Windows child processes can't inherit objects.

Also, you generally want to avoid using a global shared mutable object in your `multiprocessing` code; mutations are visible only within a single child process, but processes can be *reused*, producing inconsistent results.